# REST API with MongoDB Atlas, problem with findOne() while posting an entry in the DB

Tags: mongodb, rest, mongoose, mongodb-query

Trying to develop a REST API using MongoDB Atlas. The idea is to POST a new item into DB if the request.body.name does not exist in the database.

```
// POST '/tea'
const newTea = (req, res) => {

    // check if the tea name already exists in db
    Tea.findOne({name:req.body.name},(data) => {

        console.log(`The req.body.name is: ${req.body.name}`);
        console.log(`The value of data is: ${data}`);

        //if tea not in db, add it
        if (data === null) {
            //create a new tea object using the Tea model and req.body
            const newTea = new Tea({
                name:req.body.name,
                image: req.body.image, // placeholder for now
                description: req.body.description,
                keywords: req.body.keywords,
                origin: req.body.origin,
                brew_time: req.body.brew_time,
                temperature: req.body.temperature,
            })

            // save this object to database
            newTea.save((err, data)=>{
                if(err) return res.json({Error: err});
                return res.json(data);
            })
        // if tea is in db, return a message to inform it exists            
        } else {
            return res.json({message:`The Tea with the name: ${data.name} already exists`});
        }
    })    
};
```

The problem is that whenever I post a new Tea (newTea), if the Tea already exists in the DB (findOne by its name), it returns a new database entry, instead of a message saying that the Tea with that name already exists.

If we console.log the value of data, from Tea.findOne the value is null!!! I really do not understand what is wrong with the above code.

Thanks for you help,
Luis

I am using Mongoose.

Comment: Try check for both `null` as well as `undefined`, or just code like this: `if (! data) { // create... }`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, tested it but it requires another argument error for the callback funtion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. In fact, the callback function requires an err besides data.
I had the following block of code:

```
Tea.findOne({name:req.body.name},(data) => { ... }
```

It has to be replaced by:

```
Tea.findOne({ name: req.body.name }, (err, data) => {...}
```

Then we shall work on both data and err.